# Generate time series with daily statistics using a PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, aggregate-functions

I am finding myself in the position of having to formulate a (to me) rather complex SQL query and I can't seem to get my head around it.

I have a table called `orders` and a related table `order_state_history` that logs the state of those orders over time (see below).

I now need to generate a series of rows - one row per day - containing the amount of orders that were in particular states at the end of that day (see `report`). Also I want to consider only orders of `order.type = 1`.

The data resides in a PostgreSQL database. I already found out how to generate a time series using `GENERATE_SERIES(DATE '2001-01-01', CURRENT_DATE, '1 DAY'::INTERVAL) days` which allows me to generate rows for days on which no state changes were recorded.

My current approach is to join `orders`, `order_state_history` and the generated series of `days` all together and try to filter out all the rows that have `DATE(order_state_history.timestamp) > DATE(days)` and then somehow get the final state of each order on that day by `first_value(order_state_history.new_state) OVER (PARTITION_BY(orders.id) ORDER BY order_state_history.timestamp DESC)`, but this is where my tiny bit of SQL experience abandons me.

I just can't wrap my head around the problem.

Can this even be solved in a single query or would I be better adviced to compute the data by some kind of intelligent script that performs one query per day?
What would be a reasonable approach to the problem?

```
orders===            
id       type        
10000    1        
10001    1        
10002    2        
10003    2        
10004    1        


order_state_history===            
order_id    index    timestamp           new_state
10000       1        01.01.2001 12:00    NEW
10000       2        02.01.2001 13:00    ACTIVE
10000       3        03.01.2001 14:00    DONE
10001       1        02.01.2001 13:00    NEW
10002       1        03.01.2001 14:00    NEW
10002       2        05.01.2001 10:00    ACTIVE
10002       3        05.01.2001 14:00    DONE
10003       1        07.01.2001 04:00    NEW
10004       1        05.01.2001 14:00    NEW
10004       2        10.01.2001 17:30    DONE


Expected result===            
date          new_orders    active_orders    done_orders
01.01.2001    1             0                0
02.01.2001    1             1                0
03.01.2001    1             0                1
04.01.2001    1             0                1
05.01.2001    2             0                1
06.01.2001    2             0                1
07.01.2001    2             0                1
08.01.2001    2             0                1
09.01.2001    2             0                1
10.01.2001    1             0                2
```

Comment: Please, check the expected results (why are there 2 NEW orders on 03.01?) and add next expected rows until 05.01 at least.

Comment: I added all relevant rows. On 03.01. there are two NEW orders because on both 02.01. and 03.01. there were new orders created (10001 and 10002). Order 10001 **stays** on state NEW, so it is counted on all the days following. The counts are totals, result row `new_orders` counts all orders that are in state NEW on the end of the day, whether their status changed or not.

Comment: But 10002 is of type 2 so shouldn't be counted?

Comment: You are right of course. I've updated the data accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1. Calculate a cumulative sum of state for each order, using values NEW = 1, ACTIVE = 1, DONE = 2:

```
select 
    order_id, timestamp::date as day, 
    sum(case new_state when 'DONE' then 2 else 1 end) over w as state
from order_state_history h
join orders o on o.id = h.order_id
where o.type = 1
window w as (partition by order_id order by timestamp)

 order_id |    day     | state 
----------+------------+-------
    10000 | 2001-01-01 |     1
    10000 | 2001-01-02 |     2
    10000 | 2001-01-03 |     4
    10001 | 2001-01-02 |     1
    10004 | 2001-01-05 |     1
    10004 | 2001-01-10 |     3
(6 rows)
```

Step 2. Calculate a transition matrix for each order based on states from step 1 (2 means NEW->ACTIVE, 3 means NEW->DONE, 4 means ACTIVE->DONE):

```
select 
    order_id, day, state,
    case when state = 1 then 1 when state = 2 or state = 3 then -1 else 0 end as new,
    case when state = 2 then 1 when state = 4 then -1 else 0 end as active,
    case when state > 2 then 1 else 0 end as done
from (
    select 
        order_id, timestamp::date as day, 
        sum(case new_state when 'DONE' then 2 else 1 end) over w as state
    from order_state_history h
    join orders o on o.id = h.order_id
    where o.type = 1
    window w as (partition by order_id order by timestamp)
    ) s

 order_id |    day     | state | new | active | done 
----------+------------+-------+-----+--------+------
    10000 | 2001-01-01 |     1 |   1 |      0 |    0
    10000 | 2001-01-02 |     2 |  -1 |      1 |    0
    10000 | 2001-01-03 |     4 |   0 |     -1 |    1
    10001 | 2001-01-02 |     1 |   1 |      0 |    0
    10004 | 2001-01-05 |     1 |   1 |      0 |    0
    10004 | 2001-01-10 |     3 |  -1 |      0 |    1
(6 rows)
```

Step 3. Calculate a cumulative sum of each state for a series of days:

```
select distinct
    day::date,
    sum(new) over w as new,
    sum(active) over w as active,
    sum(done) over w as done
from generate_series('2001-01-01'::date, '2001-01-10', '1d'::interval) day
left join (
    select 
        order_id, day, state,
        case when state = 1 then 1 when state = 2 or state = 3 then -1 else 0 end as new,
        case when state = 2 then 1 when state = 4 then -1 else 0 end as active,
        case when state > 2 then 1 else 0 end as done
    from (
        select 
            order_id, timestamp::date as day, 
            sum(case new_state when 'DONE' then 2 else 1 end) over w as state
        from order_state_history h
        join orders o on o.id = h.order_id
        where o.type = 1
        window w as (partition by order_id order by timestamp)
        ) s
    ) s
using(day)
window w as (order by day)
order by 1

    day     | new | active | done 
------------+-----+--------+------
 2001-01-01 |   1 |      0 |    0
 2001-01-02 |   1 |      1 |    0
 2001-01-03 |   1 |      0 |    1
 2001-01-04 |   1 |      0 |    1
 2001-01-05 |   2 |      0 |    1
 2001-01-06 |   2 |      0 |    1
 2001-01-07 |   2 |      0 |    1
 2001-01-08 |   2 |      0 |    1
 2001-01-09 |   2 |      0 |    1
 2001-01-10 |   1 |      0 |    2
(10 rows)
```