# PostgreSQL - Find number of installs each day given a table of installs and uninstalls

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table for machine installations in this way:

```
installationID, machineID, installed_at, uninstalled_at
A, 1, 2020-01-01, Null
B, 2, 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02
C, 3, 2020-01-02, Null
D, 2, 2020-01-04, Null
```

I need a query that returns the number of installed machines per day.
Like this:

```
Date, installed
2020-01-01, 2
2020-01-02, 3
2020-01-03, 2 
2020-01-04, 3
```

I know that given a date, say '2020-01-03', I can get the number of installed machines as follows:

```sql
SELECT date, count(machineID) 
from installs 
where installed_at >= '2020-01-03' 
and (uninstalled_at is Null or uninstalled_at <= '2020-01-03')
```

However, I do not know how to query in such a way I can get the result for all dates at one query.

Comment: Use a calendar table or generate a series of dates on the fly. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html

Comment: I figured I should use a generate_series, but I do not know what to do with that. I need to pass a data to the filter, or should I call the query in the filter (whatever that means >.< )

Comment: This might answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890142/generate-time-series-with-daily-statistics-using-a-postgresql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generated series from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-15. Adjust '<= / >' as needed.

```
select generate_series dt, count(*) n
from  generate_series('2020-01-01'::timestamp , '2020-01-15'::timestamp, '1 day')  
left join tbl on installed_at <= generate_series and ( uninstalled_at is null or uninstalled_at > generate_series)
group by generate_series
order by generate_series;
```

Comment: hum... this seems to work, but I am using redshift and I get `FeatureNotSupported: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables ` I guess redshift is not as close to postgresql as I thought

Comment: This guy had the same problem as I had with redshift: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102019/error-in-query-to-redshift

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate the dates.  Then `left join` and `group by` to count the installations:

```
select gs.date, count(i.installationId)
from generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-01-04'::date, interval '1 day') gs(date) left join
     installations i
     on i.installed_at >= gs.date and
        9i.uninstalled_at > gs.date or i.uninstalled_at is null)
group by gs.date
order by gs.date;
```

Note:  You appear to be counting the uninstall date as an "installation".  I would expect that not to count.